# Inserting CURRENTDATE for DATE column fails in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

i am trying to insert CURRENTDATE as the value for a field that has the type defined as "Timestamp without Timezone".

```
INSERT INTO monthly_forecasts VALUES
('1','DIV1','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','','','','','-3',CURRENTDATE, CURRENTDATE)
```

But I get this error when I do that:

```
ERROR:  column "currentdate" does not exist
LINE 2: ...'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','','','','','-3',CURRENTDAT...
                                                         ^
```

How do I insert current date as the value for this field? Please help!

Comment: Unrelated, but: numbers should not be enclosed in single quotes. `'1'` is a varchar value, `1` is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) the function is named `current_date`, not `currentdate`.

But as your column is defined as  timestamp, you should use `current_timestamp` to include the time of the day (a DATE doesn't have a time)